# SQL Server Merge statement issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, insert

I have 3 tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE VersionsProjects
(
    IdVersionProject INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Version INT
);

CREATE TABLE Parameters 
(
    IdParameter INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    IdVersionProject INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (IdVersionProject) REFERENCES VersionsProjects(IdVersionProject)
);

CREATE TABLE Questions 
(
    IdQuestion INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Text VARCHAR(50),
    IdParameter INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdParameter) REFERENCES Parameters(IdParameter)
);
```

When I create a new insert in `VersionsProjects`, I duplicate all the rows in parameters related to old `versionsProjects` and duplicate all the rows in questions related to duplicate parameters.

Example :

```
DECLARE @TempParametersDuplicated TABLE (Old_ID_Parameter INT, New_ID_Parameter INT)

MERGE INTO Parameters T1
USING (SELECT IdParameter, Name
       FROM Parameters P
       WHERE IdVersionProject = @OldIdVersionProject) T2 ON 1 = 0

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN
        INSERT (Name, IdVersionProject)
        VALUES (T2.Name, @NewIdVersionProject)
        OUTPUT T2.IdParameter, INSERTED.IdParameter INTO TempParametersDuplicated;

MERGE INTO Parameters T1
USING (SELECT Text, T.New_ID as IdParameter
       FROM Questions Q
       INNER JOIN @TempParametersDuplicated T ON Q.IdParameter = T.Old_ID
       WHERE IdVersionProject = @OldIdVersionProject) T2 ON 1 = 0

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN
        INSERT (Text, IdParameter)
        VALUES (T2.Text, T2.IdParameter);
```

**My first question**: is the method I'm using the best? Or is there a cleaner way to do the same thing ?

**My second question**: I heard that the merge command is really unreliable. Should I be worried about it? Sometime, I have more than 300k rows to insert.

Comment: "Is the method I'm using the best?" - define best? Does it meet your requirements? Only you can answer.

Comment: There are a number of articles about the issues with the merge statement. I recommend taking a read.

Comment: Given you only have one condition, `MERGE...WHEN NOT MATCHED` could just as easily be `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`, and there are reported consistency issues with `MERGE` so it would probably make sense to use that instead. This applies to the second statement only, the first statement cannot use `INSERT` because the `OUTPUT` refers to a table other than `inserted`.